# How to pass a date parameter from report builder query designer to oracle database

Tags: oracle, date, reporting-services, reporting, oraclereports

i'm using report builder 3.0 connected to oracle database.
i'm trying to pass a date parameter in the query with no success, i don't know the exact syntax.
I've tried :

```
SELECT * 
FROM igeneral.GCL_CLAIMS
WHERE CREATED_BY IN (:CREATED_BY) AND CLAIM_YEAR IN(:UW_YEAR)  
  AND (Trunc(LOSS_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN to_char(':From', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
  AND to_char('To', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

i got this error: `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

also i've tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM igeneral.GCL_CLAIMS 
WHERE CREATED_BY IN (:CREATED_BY) AND CLAIM_YEAR IN(:UW_YEAR)  
  AND (LOSS_DATE BETWEEN ':From' AND ':To')
```

i got this error: `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

thanks

Comment: the ':FROM' and ':To' looks suspicious to me.  I believe you're trying to have the engine cast the text ':FROM' to a mm/dd/yyyy format.  I believe you don't want the tics; and don't you mean to_date instead of to_char?  The :FROM and :To are likely already strings being passed in right and need to be converted to dates in order to utilize the between correctly.

Comment: your right i mean to_date, i tried to_char since i found a post online using to_char instead of to_date but didnt work. From and To are the parameters; can you give me the correct syntax to use??

Comment: Should just have to remove the tics  variable/paramaters shoudln't be wrapped in tics.  the data type is known since it had to be passed in as a parameter so you don't need tics around them.

Comment: i tried it but didnt work, can you give me the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on the `data type` of the from and to parameter.

If your parameter is `DATE` datatype, use `to_char` to conver date into a literal of the required format you want to display. Else, if the parameter is `VARCHAR2` datatype, use `to_date` to convert the date literal to date for comparision.

In your case, it is probable that `LOSS_DATE` column is a DATE, and your parameters are literals, so use `TO_DATE on the parameters using proper format mask.

`LOSS_DATE BETWEEN to_date(':From', 'mm/dd/yyyy') AND to_date('To', 'mm/dd/yyyy')`

Comment: i tried as you suggested, the dataset saved without error, however when running the report an error occure "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number"

Comment: If the data is inserted in the database perfectly, it means there is a mismatch in the data type while generating the report.

Comment: how can i track it, i tried to convert all fields to date using To_Date function but didnt work

Comment: Did you use the exact `date format`? By the way, in your reports, are you using `TO_DATE` or `CAST`?

Comment: im using To_Date and loss_type field are having value like this one "1/13/2014  11:24:00 AM", From and To are parameters having date/time data Type

Comment: Try `TRUNC` on the `loss_type` field. If the field is DATE, then use trunc directly, else if it is literal, use `TO_DATE` with the required format.

Answer (score 0):

The error,  ORA-01036: illegal variable name/numberbeing, typically occurs in an Oracle Report when the parameter identified in the object navigator does not correspond with a bind variable referenced in a query.

Does your `:From` and `:To` bind variables appear in "User Parameters" in your Object Navigator? **I did notice that your code cited does not have the colon preceding it for the `:To` bind variable.**

**Correct Example**

Here is a screenshot of a seeded Oracle Report's "User Parameters"....and specifically the `:p_as_of_date` bind variable. Notice with the pictured Property Inspector, one identifies a datatype and an Input Mask. Did you set parameters, `:From` and `:To`, in this manner? Specifically, if your parameter is being used as a date, I would make sure that Datatype is set to Date in the Property Inspector.
[image]

Here is an snippet of the :p_as_of_date bind variable in a "seeded" Oracle Report and here it is being referenced in a query:

```
 where      TRUNC(ps.gl_date)    <= :p_as_of_date
```

**Notice that no casting is needed**.
With your query, I would take this approach (again, no casting):

```
AND TRUNC(LOSS_DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') BETWEEN :From AND :To
```

Consequently, I would just make sure the bind variable cited in "User Parameters" correspond with the bind variables in your query.

Comment: i tried the above, but after i click OK to save, a popup window "Define Query Parameters" listing all my parameters with Parameter Name and Parameter Value columns, after i click OK another error occur "ORA-01745:invalid host/bind variable name".

Also note that in query design i don't have visual interface of tables and views same as your object navigator screen, i can only write queries; is there a way to show it since it will facilitate alot of work